# NSPopupButton with Live Fonts (Styled Text)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nspopupbutton

I wonder if it's possible to show live fonts in a popupbutton control (**NSPopupButton**)?  currently, I load a popupbutton with a list of fonts available in the following manner.

```
NSArray *familyNames = [[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] availableFontFamilies];
NSMutableArray *fontarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
[fontarray addObject:@"- Select one - "];
for (NSString *family in familyNames) {
    [fontarray addObject:family];
}
[fontmenu1p addItemsWithTitles:fontarray];
```

Maybe, something like the following, using NSMutableAttributedString?

```
for (NSString *family in familyNames) {
    NSDictionary *attr1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:family size:[NSFont systemFontSize]],NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil];
    NSMutableAttributedString *aString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:family];
    [aString setAttributes:attr1 range:NSMakeRange(0,family.length-1)];
    [fontarray addObject:aString];
}
[fontmenu1p addItemsWithTitles:fontarray];
```

I get an out of bounds error.  I don't know if my approach is right.  I don't even know if the popupbutton control supports styled text.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where did you get the out of bounds error?

Comment: I think it's the last line.  I can't exactly tell since there are more than a hundred fonts to follow.  Thanks.

Comment: My first thought was that fontarray could be empty.  Actually, it's not.  I get 348 if I count the number of items.  In fact, if I display one of the objects with NSLog, I get the following.  Arial Blac{
    NSColor = "NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Arial-Black 13.00 pt. P [] (0x100528bc0) fobj=0x101b36150, spc=4.34\"";  So I guess NSPopupButton cannot display styled text?  Well, you can do it with VisualBasic/C#.  So I thought I could do it with Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

Even I did not tested it, I think, that our approach will not work. NSPopUpButton has a convenient API for its menu. Convenient, but short. (Typically pop-up items are not attributed, no separate views and so on.)

I would try to build an instance of [NSMenuItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for each item. There is a setter [-setAttributedTitle:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItem/setAttributedTitle%3a), which lets you set attributed strings. Then you have to aggregate this to an instance of [NSMenu](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [set the menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPopUpButton/setMenu%3a) to the pop-up button.

BTW: [aString setAttributes:attr1 range:NSMakeRange(0,family.length-1)];
Why -1? The length is the length, not the index of the last char. And you want to set a range, which takes the length, not the index of the last character, too.

Comment: Umm...  I first set the size to family.length.  After seeing an error, I changed it to family.length - 1.  I wasn't sure.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Of course: You had an index problem and it is the first thing to do to reduce ranges. But I do not think that this is the problem.